# Не могу разобраться со строками в Питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дана строка. Если она представляет собой запись целого числа, то вывести 1, если вещественного (с дробной частью) — вывести 2; если строку нельзя преобразовать в число, то вывести 0. Нужен код на Python, пожалуйста.

Comment: старайтесь использовать более содержательные заголовки, которые отражают вашу проблему [ask]

Answer (score 3):

```
a = '-5'

try:
    if float(a) // 1 == float(a):  # Можно if float(a) % 1 == 0
        print(1)
    else:
        print(2)
except ValueError:
    print(0)
```